# Lie group framing and framed bordism

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, cobordism

1. What is the definition of Lie group framing, in simple terms?
2. Is the Lie group framing of spheres a particular type of Lie group framing? (How special is the Lie group framing of spheres differed from the generality of Lie group framing?)
3. Examples of Lie group framing includes:

- $\Omega_3^\text{fr}=\mathbf{Z}/{24}$ generated by a 3-sphere $S_3=\operatorname{SU}(2)$ with the Lie group framing.
- $\Omega_6^\text{fr}=\mathbf{Z}/{2}$ generated by $S_3 \times S_3$ with the Lie group framing.

How do we construct the explicit class of $\mathbf{Z}/{24}$ and $\mathbf{Z}/{2}$ class of Lie group framing above?

["Framed bordism" at the Manifold Atlas Project](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Framed_bordism)

Comment: My understanding of the term is that left multiplication on a Lie group gives a trivialization of its tangent bundle.  That's typically called "the" Lie group framing, although there is another one due to right multiplication.   Since the $3$-sphere is a Lie group, it has its left-invariant framing, which is essentially unique up to the framing of the tangent space of the identity.  Similarly, the product of  two Lie groups is a Lie group.

Comment: Thanks @RyanBudney is this paper related - Lie groups as framed manifolds
- Erich Ossa -https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938382900131

Comment: Yes, that paper is using the same basic idea.

Comment: could you write up an answer? please thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Lie group framing is a reference to the group action.  A Lie group $G$ acts on the left of $G$ by the map

$$(g,h) \longmapsto gh.$$

Similarly there are actions on the right, and conjugation actions, etc.  The left-invariant vector fields on $G$ correspond to the elements of $T_e G$.  So any basis for $T_e G$ extends to a unique left-invariant framing of the tangent bundle $TG$.

So for example, the $3$-sphere has left-invariant vector fields

$$S^3 \ni g \longmapsto (g,gv) \in TS^3$$

where $v \in T_1 S^3$, i.e. $v$  is orthogonal to $1 \in \mathbb R$ as a vector in $\mathbb R^4$, and we are using quaternionic multiplication.

This gives the framing of $TS^3$,

$$S^3 \ni g \longmapsto (g, gi, gj, gk) \in FS^3.$$

$FS^3$ is the frame bundle to $TS^3$, i.e. it consists of a point $g \in S^3$ together with three linearly independent  vectors in $T_g S^3$.

You can visualize this framing in terms of the Hopf fibration.

[image]

The first  vector field $(g,gi)$ is tangent to the fibers of the Hopf
fibration, and the other two are normal to the fibration, where the normal vector fields wind about the fibers.

I think if you use right multiplication instead of left multiplication for all the definitions you get the opposite twisting of the normal vector fields.

Comment: Thanks +1 - do you have comments about How do we construct the explicit class of /24 and /2 class of Lie group framing above?

Comment: I think the $\Omega_3^{fr}$ is $\pi_8 S^5$,  so you're talking about a 3-sphere embedded in $\mathbb R^8$ with a framing of its normal bundle.  In this dimension all embedded $3$-spheres are isotopic, so it's the standard linearly embedded sphere, and the framings are parametrized by $\pi_3 SO_5 \simeq \pi_3 SO_4 \simeq \mathbb{Z}^2$.  The language "Lie group framing" appears to have been a choice of terminology by Martin Olbermann, the person that wrote that Manifold Atlas page you link to.    It might require a conversation with him to verify, but what I suspect he means is that there is...

Comment: Thanks so much, I also asked this https://mathoverflow.net/q/460345/505775 maybe you know the differences?

Comment: a homomorphism $S^3 \to SO_4 \to SO_8$ that acts transitively on this linearly embedded $S^3$ in $\mathbb R^8$, so the normal framing comes from taking a basis for the normal bundle and translating it around.